# How to use FormData?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a link like this: `file://.....`. I'm trying to upload this file to the web server using this code:

```
  var imageData = 'file://......';
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file-input', imageData);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "my_url");
  xhr.send(formData);
```

But my servers says that file-input are undefined.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't pull files with the `file://`. You would have to upload it with an input with type `file`. If you could just access local systems you could pull any file from any user's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Get File From Static Variable

```
var formData = new FormData();
    var imageData = 'https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/pyNVUg5EM0j.png';
    formData.append('file',imageData);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "my_url");
    xhr.send(formData);
```

You can get your file in my_url.php using `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);`

**Solution 2**

Get File From Input Type File Field (Upload File)

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imageData = document.getElementById('the-file');
formData.append('file',imageData.files[0]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/test2/phpFile.php");
xhr.send(formData);
```

You can get your file in my_url.php using `echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);`